# есть ли аналоги в ga4 параметрам universal analytics (ga:entrances, ga:bounces, ga:pageLoadTime, ga:pageLoadSample)?

Tags: google-analytics

есть ли аналоги в ga4 параметрам universal analytics?
ga:entrances,
ga:bounces,
ga:pageLoadTime,
ga:pageLoadSample